# In Torch how do I create a 1-hot tensor from a list of integer labels?

Tags: indexing, torch, one-hot-encoding

I have a byte tensor of integer class labels, e.g. from the MNIST data set.

```
 1
 7
 5
[torch.ByteTensor of size 3]
```

How do use it to create a tensor of 1-hot vectors?

```
 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 3x10]
```

I know I could do this with a loop, but I'm wondering if there's any clever Torch indexing that will get it for me in a single line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
indices = torch.LongTensor{1,7,5}:view(-1,1)
one_hot = torch.zeros(3, 10)
one_hot:scatter(2, indices, 1)
```

You can find the documentation for `scatter` in the [torch/torch7 github readme](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor-scatterdim-index-srcval) (in the master branch).

Comment: Which language is this? I have never seen this syntax

Answer (score 3):

An alternate method is to shuffle rows from an identity matrix:

```
indicies = torch.LongTensor{1,7,5}
one_hot = torch.eye(10):index(1, indicies)
```

This was not my idea, I found it in [karpathy/char-rnn](https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn/blob/master/util/OneHot.lua).